# How do I select all headlines with one command?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this in my CSS file

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  color: red;
}
```

Is there a way to select all headlines with one statement like

```
h* {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I don't think you can but I hope I'm wrong

Comment: Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: You can with LESS and recursion (see duplicate question linked by Zenith), but it's an unnecessary amount of code compared to a simple comma-separated list of 6 items.

Comment: Your first block of code is already well optimised, clean and maintainable.  Is a h* equivalent really required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way you can do this in standard CSS. You will have to work with a comma separated list.

You can however accomplish this using stylesheet languages such as SASS and LESS.

Comment: This didn't really warrant an answer. Read the comments first. Everything you've said in your "answer" was said in the comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, @AlexThomas, the comments weren't there yet when I answered the question.